# IIS10 + wordpress. Login page fails: refreshes without error on form submit, recovery page refreshes with ERROR: Enter a username or email address

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, iis-10

I run WordPress on IIS10 on Windows Server 2016. When I try to login the page simply refreshes without any logged errors (not on screen, developer console or WordPress logs).

When I try the WordPress lost password screen (wp-login.php?action=lostpassword) and enter my username or email address I get:

> ERROR: Enter a username or email address.

I tried everything as suggested here:

- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72010/i-cant-access-my-site-via-wp-admin
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203850/can-not-login-with-correct-username-and-password
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67328/show-errors-on-custom-login-form
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/i-cant-access-my-wordpress-dashboard-shows-warning-message
- https://www.thetechtrackers.com/2019/06/table-prefix-must-not-be-empty.html (tried adding a new user manually in table `wp_users` and added `wp_capabilities`=`a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` in table `wp_usermeta`)

To summarize what I tried:

- Renamed folder 'plugins' to 'plugins_backup'
- Ran `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`
- added lines to wp-config for
  define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com');
  define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');
- template is reset to "twentyseventeen"
- deleted cookies
- set `WP_DEBUG` and 'WP_DEBUG_LOG' to `true` in wp-config, though still no errors show when trying to login and also no logfile is created in wp-content folder.
- [wp_usermeta] wp_capabilities field for my user has value `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`, so I'm an admin
- Repaired all MySQL database tables via mysqlcheck -r [database]
- In [wp_options] I then updated fields `siteurl` and `home` from my existing url (https://www.example.com/wordpress) to a random web address: "www.whatever.com". After login I'm now redirected to this address. So it almost seems the login IS succesful, but somehow it cannot load.
- I also tried a NEW completely fresh install, but in the installation wizard I'm running into `table prefix must not be empty` error (which I why I tried the solution from thetechtrackers site, see above)
- As a final attempt I copied the entire Wordpress folder of another site on this server that DOES work correctly and changed the `DB_NAME` field in `wp-config.php`, still the same login page redirect happens

I have no idea what else to try now..

PS. I had this posted on the Wordpress stack exchange before, but got 0 replies after 2 months. Since I also think this might be related to IIS/Windows security/server settings, trying it here and potentially start a bounty.

Comment: WordPress uses its own security system, so has nothing to do with IIS/Windows. IIS merely works as a reverse proxy server for PHP apps. If no one would like to work on this issue for free, you should consider hiring a consultant somewhere or use WordPress commercial support if you really want to resolve it.